# Is it possible to Implement SAML and Firebase for Mobile Device in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, saml, google-identity

So I think the title is mostly self explanatory. I'm working with a group who has a SAML SSO setup. They want to use their SAML login to access an instance of Firebase. Is this possible?

There are a couple of things I've found about Firebase and SAML. There's this one from Google: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/saml#redirect

There's also this medium post: https://medium.com/@tfalvo/single-sign-on-sso-for-your-firebase-app-with-saml-f67c71e0b4d6

They both require Google Identify Provider, which is fine. The issue is that in Flutter, firebase auth redirect and popup are only available in web, not for mobile.

For practice, I've been able to use WebView, listen while I login, catch the SAML response, decode it, and then take whatever information I need from it. However, I can't figure out a good way to have firebase authenticate any of this information.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have any news? Would love to here them ;-)

Comment: do you have any news on this

Comment: Afraid not. Using WebView was the best we got, but it still didn't work very well. We kind of gave up on it I'm afraid.